# REST API: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: rest, acumatica, dac

I am having issues accessing data from a DAC that has any amount of customization with it. I have a DAC with a few more complicated modifications, so I will start with the simple one. I have modified the **External Reference** field of `SO.SOOrder`. This is the only change to the DAC.

**Originial Attributes**

```
[PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "External Reference")]
```

**Customize Attributes (Replace Original)**

```
[PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Some Text Here")]
```

Now, when I attempt to access any `SalesOrder` via the REST API:

```
GET https://site.acumatica.com/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO000123
```

The following error is returned:

```json
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.",
    "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.FillEntityImplWithKeys(String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, String[] keys)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.SoapFacade.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.FillEntityImplWithKeys(EntityImpl entity, String[] keys)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.CreateEntityFromKeys(String objectName, String idsString)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Now, I'm not certain if this is occurring because of my DAC modification or not, but I cannot find anything else linking this and my other troubled DAC `CustomerLocation` to the same error message.

Where do I go from here to identify what what the *bad state* is?

Comment: What Acumatica version are you on? I know it is something past 2017 just what exact build is it?

Comment: The exact version is `17.205.0015`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this screen contains multiple key fields (Order Type and Order Nbr.), you need to put them all in the URL.

```
GET https://site.acumatica.com/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO000123
```

gets changed into if this is a type SO Sales Order

```
GET https://site.acumatica.com/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/000123
```

SO is order type and 00123 is Order number

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. I am using the Swagger file [outlined here](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(16))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ca2716f1-025a-4a6e-9090-797cf32b0459) and none of the examples show this /SO/ intermediate path. I see now your solution is outlined in the URL section of the [Retrieve a Record by Key Fields](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(13))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=52c97a83-1fa1-40e9-8219-52a89a91f2da) section of the docs.

Comment: Acumatica changed their documentation to be by release... so here is the new [Retreive a Record by Key Fields](https://help-2017r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=52c97a83-1fa1-40e9-8219-52a89a91f2da) link.

Answer (score 1):

This exception message can also result from having a slash character at the end of the Request URL, after the Key field(s)

Exception:

http://site.acuamtica.com/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/SO123456/

Successful:

http://site.acuamtica.com/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/SO123456